# Is it possible to open the WebBrowser after clicking on a label in Dynamics AX?

Tags: axapta

Is it possible to open a Web Brower (IE/Chrome/Firefox) after clicking a button/label/StringEdit on a form in Dynamics AX?

Thank you in advance.

I develop in MS Dynamics AX 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Info.urlLookup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/info.urllookup).

```
infoLog.urlLookup('http://nameofthepageyouwanttoopen.com');
```

As stated [here](http://axaptafreak.blogspot.be/2008/03/open-web-pages-from-x-code.html).

Or you can use the method as described [here](http://dynamics-ax-dev.blogspot.be/2010/06/open-url-in-browser-from-x.html).

```
void clicked()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process pr = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo si = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo('URL HERE');
    pr.set_StartInfo(si);
    pr.Start();
}
```

Comment: Or another possibility: http://dynamics-ax-dev.blogspot.be/2010/06/open-url-in-browser-from-x.html .

Comment: Your comment should be the answer :p, Thank you so much